# RSS feed from Hackernews

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rss

I am trying to set up [an RSS feed](http://news.ycombinator.com/rss) using Microsoft Outlook from hackernews. Outlook is my mail client to check my office mails. (Email server using POP3.)

But when I say *Subscribe now*, it it opens Outlook on my Windows PC, but it gives an error as below.

[image]

1. What is the problem here? Do I need to change some setting in Outlook for this RSS feed?
2. How can I fix this to see Hackernews RSS feeds using my Outlook?

EDITED: Same error occurs when I try to subscribe to RSS feeds from `reddit/r/programming`.

Comment: Which version on Outlook? I just tried in Outlook 2007 & it works fine

Comment: @Sathya.Outlook-2007. Can u pls. let know if any settings have to be enabled/disabled in Outlook Email account or somewhere in outlook. What is the URL you see when you subscribe using outlook. is it feed://news.ycombinator.com/rss or http://news.ycombinator.com/rss. For me it Outlook is still saying, Navigation to webpage cancelled, retype the address and try again. but no success with either or the above urls i typed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just right clicked on RSS Feeds -> Add a new RSS feed, and entered `http://news.ycombinator.com/rss` as the URL for the RSS feed. After this Outlook fetched the RSS automatically & had no problems.

---

If this doesn't help you out, do have a look at [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917125) which explains how to setup RSS under Outlook to use NTLM authentication

Comment: @thanks but no luck for me. Would it matter if I am behind a office firewall/router? Basically trying to narrow if some global network related issue or something to do with my PC outlook setting or windows firewall setting on my PC? Any guess?

Comment: @goldenmean what does opening the same URL in the browser give you?

Comment: @Sathya: for Hackernews: i get this page where it asks to subscribe to this page using - different tools,  hackernews: http://news.ycombinator.com/rss  and for Reddit/r/programming the link: http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.rss goes to same subscribe page. Plus the subscriptions worked using google reader. But using with outlook is the glitch.

Comment: google reader simply means google can open it. it wouldn't have any effect should some web filter at your office block it. I'd guess someone decided to block the word 'hack' ;)

Comment: Can you have a look at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917125) and see if that helps?

Comment: @Sathya: thanks a lot. Pls. post your comment above as answer. It fixed my error. Would like to mark it accepted.

Comment: @goldenmean done.